# How do I convert a dropdown which switch between all and fav reports into single button in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, frontend

**I had a drop-down for switching reports type all to fav. Now I want to change it into a single button, a Single button which initially shows All reports then clicks onto it changes to Fav reports and then re-click to initial state**

[image of drop down i created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHHw5.png)

code for component dropdown yourReportDropDown.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
    Grid,
    Typography,
    Paper,
    makeStyles,
    createStyles,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import ClickAwayListener from "@material-ui/core/ClickAwayListener";
import Popover from "@material-ui/core/Popover";
import Radio from "@material-ui/core/Radio";
import ReportIcon from '../../../../images/allReport.png';
import FavoriteIcon from '../../../../images/favorite.png';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
    createStyles({
        rowAlign: {
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "row",
        },
        fontStyle: {
            fontFamily: "Montserrat",
        },
        scrollBar: {
            "&::-webkit-scrollbar": {
                width: 5,
                borderRadius: 17,
            },
            "&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb": {
                background: "#ffB800",
                borderRadius: 17,
            },
        },
        onHover:{
            "&:hover": {
                backgroundColor: '#fff7e1'
            },
        }
    })
);

const YourReportDropDown = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

    const handleClick = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
        setRotateVal(180);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
        setRotateVal(0);
    };

    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

    const [rotateVal, setRotateVal] = useState(0);

    const handleSelected = (e, filterType, element) => {
        props.handleChange(e, filterType, element);
        handleClose();
    };

    useEffect(() => {}, [props.dropDownList]);

    //   console.log("countries", props.dropDownList);
    return (
        <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClose}>
            <div
                style={{
                    width: "100%",
                    width: 211,
                    marginLeft: props.filterType === "category" ? 45 : 0,
                }}
            >
                <div
                    className={classes.rowAlign}
                    style={{
                        padding: "10px",
                        justifyContent: "space-between",
                        backgroundColor: "#e3e9ff",
                        alignItems: "center",
                        borderRadius: 4,
                        cursor: "pointer",
                    }}
                    onClick={(event) => handleClick(event)}
                >
                    <div className={classes.rowAlign} style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
                        <img
                            src={props.selectedFields === 'All' ? ReportIcon : FavoriteIcon}
                            style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
                        />
                        <Typography
                            className={classes.fontStyle}
                            style={{
                                fontSize: 18,
                                marginLeft: 13,
                                width: 123,
                                textAlign: "left",
                            }}
                            noWrap
                        >

                            {props.selectedFields}
                        </Typography>
                    </div>
                    <ExpandMoreIcon style={{ transform: `rotate(${rotateVal}deg)` }} />
                </div>

                <Popover
                    open={open}
                    onClose={handleClose}
                    anchorEl={anchorEl}
                    anchorOrigin={{
                        vertical: "bottom",
                        horizontal: "center",
                    }}
                    transformOrigin={{
                        vertical: "top",
                        horizontal: "center",
                    }}
                    style={{
                        marginTop: 10,
                        width: "100%",
                    }}
                >
                    {props.dropDownList.map((element, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div
                                className={classes.onHover}
                                key={element}
                                value={element}
                                style={{
                                    width: "100%",
                                    justifyContent: "space-between",
                                    margin: "5px 5px",
                                    width: 201,
                                    display: "flex",
                                    flexDirection: "row",
                                    alignItems: "center",
                                    cursor:'pointer'
                                }}
                                onClick={(event) =>
                                    handleSelected(event, props.filterType, element)
                                }
                            >
                                <Typography className={classes.fontStyle}>
                                    {element}
                                </Typography>

                            </div>
                        );
                    })}

                </Popover>

            </div>
        </ClickAwayListener>
    );
};

export default YourReportDropDown;
```

Section Container where i am using this drop-down code SectionContainer.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {
  createStyles,
  makeStyles,
  Typography,
  Grid,
  Paper,
  Tooltip,
  withStyles,
  Zoom,
  InputAdornment,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import ReportCard from "../reportCard";
import YourReportDropDown from "./component/yourReportDropDown";
import YourFav from "./component/fav";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
  createStyles({
    tooltip: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
      boxShadow: theme.shadows[4],
      fontSize: 14,
      fontFamilt: "Lato",
      fontWeight: "bold",
      padding: 10,
      color: "#141414",
    },
    rowAlignMent: {
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "row",
      justifyContent: "space-between",
    },
    linkHover: {
      textDecoration: "none",
      color: "#141414",
      "&:hover": {
        color: "#141414",
        textDecoration: "underline",
      },
    },
    formControl: {
      // minWidth: 180,
      // borderRadius: 8,
      // margin: theme.spacing(1),
      display: "flex",
      // alignItems:'center',
      padding: "0px 5px",
      justifyContent: "center",
      width: 260,
      height: 38,
      backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5",
      borderRadius: 5,
      fontFamily: "Montserrat",
      "&:hover": {
        borderWidth: 0,
        border: "none",
      },
    },
    selectEmpty: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    selectInput: {
      padding: "5px 10px",
      fontFamily: "Montserrat",
      fontSize: 18,
      fontWeight: "600",
      // backgroundColor:"#f5f5f5"
    },
    selectStyle: {
      fontFamily: "Montserrat",
      "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
        border: "none",
      },
      "&.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
        border: "none",
        borderRadius: 4,
      },
      "&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
        border: "none",
        borderRadius: 4,
      },
    },
    scrollBar: {
      "&::-webkit-scrollbar": {
        width: 4,
        borderRadius: 38,
        background: "#F0F0F0",
      },
      "&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb": {
        background: "#ffb800",
        borderRadius: 38,
      },
    },
  })
);

const SectionContainer = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const { reports,sectionText, filter, handleChange } = props;

  const [filterValues, setFilterValues] = useState(['All', 'Favorites'])

  return (
    <Grid item xs={6}>
      <Paper
        elevation={0}
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          padding: "16px 24px",
          // height: "auto",
          height:427,
          backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
          borderRadius: 10,
          width:window.innerWidth < 760? "90vw" : null
        }}
      >
        <div className={classes.rowAlignMent} style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
          <Typography
            style={{
              fontFamily: "Montserrat",
              fontWeight: "500",
              fontSize: 30,
              color: "#181818",
              marginBottom: 5,
              textAlign: "left",
            }}
          >
            {sectionText}
          </Typography>
          {sectionText === "Your Reports" && (
            <YourReportDropDown
            initialValue={"Type"}
            selectedFields={filter}
            dropDownList={filterValues}
            handleChange={handleChange}
            filterType={"persona"}
            // imgPath={PersonaIcon}
          />

          
          )}
        </div>

        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            marginTop: 5,
            height: '100%',
            overflowY: "auto",
            padding: 10,
            alignItems:
              sectionText === "Other Reports Relevant To You"
                ? "center"
                : "flex-start",
          }}
          className={classes.scrollBar}
        >
          <Grid container spacing={1}>
            {
              reports.length?reports.map((element, index) => {
                // if (index <= 2) {
                return (
                <ReportCard
                    key={index}
                    element={element}
                    index={index}
                    sectionText={sectionText}
                  />
                );
                // }
              })
              :
              <div
                style={{
                  height: "100%",
                  width: "100%",
                  justifyContent: "center",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  marginTop:130
                }}
              >
                <Typography
                  style={{ fontFamily: "Montserrat", textAlign: "center" }}
                >
                  No Reports to show
                </Typography>
              </div>
            }
          </Grid>
        </div>
      </Paper>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default SectionContainer;
```

Comment: It's simple toggle state logic

Comment: Hi, @NishargShah can you please provide me with a reference for it.